# how to make a special time cronjob?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

how can I make a cronjob that it runs every 5min from 7am until 12pm , and after that it runs every 10min every hour?

*If you want to do it with writing a short code please use python!
thanks :-x

Comment: I think multiple cron jobs with the same command is the only solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manipulate crontab files, [here is a nice lib for that](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/).

If you want to write python script that able to scedule periodic tasks (like cron does) [APScheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/) will be a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use two cron entries.

One way is to use one cron entry to run every hour of every day on the 10's. Then have another cron entry to run on the 5's from 7 to 12.

```
*/10 * * * * *
5,15,25,35,45,55 7-23 * * * *
```

Another way runs every 5 minutes from 7 to 12 and every 10 minutes from 12 to 7.

```
*/5 7-23 * * * * *
*/10 0-6 * * * * *
```